# Add dynamic getter/setter properties to a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying add getter/setter properties to a function, TypeScript doesn't complain until I'm trying access that property.

```
const obj:{[key:string]:string} = {
  blah: "ok",
  test: "yes"
};

const func = (a:string):void => {};

for(const key in obj)
{
  Object.defineProperty(func, key, {
    get() { return obj[key]},
    set(a:string) {
      obj[key] = a;
    }
  });
}
console.log([func]); //good, shows function and new properties
console.log(func.blah); //error TS2339: Property 'blah' does not exist on type '(a: string) => void'.
```

I'm trying avoid "any" and property names as type declarations.

Any tips?

Comment: `obj` is defined as `{[key:string]:string}` -- do we want to only allow accessing known properties `func.blah` and `func.test` or do we want to access any property?  Basically you need to assert the type of `func` before you add the properties: `const func = ((a:string) => {}) as ((a:string) => void) & {[key:string]:string};
`

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Would you post it as a solution, so I can upvote?

Comment: Nice avatar )))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `as` to assert the type of `func` as something which includes the properties that you are adding.

With the index signature from `obj`:

```
const func = ((a:string) => {}) as ((a:string) => void) & {[key:string]:string};
```

With a dynamic type from `typeof obj`:

```
const func = ((a:string) => {}) as ((a:string) => void) & typeof obj;
```

With some specific set of properties (could be just `blah` and `test` instead of any `string`):

```
const func = ((a:string) => {}) as ((a:string) => void) & SomeInterface;
```